# Java SignedObject isn't Serialized properly

Tags: java, serialization, java-security

It seems like `java.security.SignedObject` doesn't serialize properly.

When I do the following on a single process, it works fine:

```
Signature signingEngine = Signature.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
PublicKey pubKey; // Already initialized appropriately
PrivateKey privKey; // "     "           "
SignedObject so = new SignedObject(myObject, privKey, signingEngine);
so.verify(pubKey, signingEngine); // returns true
```

However, when I have two processes and try to pass the signed object over the network, I run into problems.

**Sender**

```
Signature signingEngine = Signature.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
PrivateKey privKey; // Already initialized appropriately
SignedObject so = new SignedObject(myObject, privKey, signingEngine);
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(so);
out.close();
```

**Receiver**

```
Signature signingEngine = Signature.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");
PublicKey pubKey; // Already initialized appropriately
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(4000);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.accept().getInputStream());
SignedObject so = (SignedObject) in.readObject();
in.close();
so.verify(pubKey, signingEngine); // returns false
```

Note that `myObject` implements `Serializable`, and even when I change `myObject` to a primitive such as a `byte[]`, I still have the same problem. Interestingly, if I send the signed object over a socket to a different thread running in the same process, `verify` succeeds.

I thought that it might be something with the `Signature` instance, but `verify` succeeds in a single process even when I sign and verify with different instances of `Signature`.

I doubt there's any issue with the keys, as in both the one process and sender/receiver case, I'm loading them from files in the exact same way.

Comment: What exactly are the problems? What type of exception and where in the code?

Comment: The issue is that SignedObject.verify returns false in the two process case.

Comment: Are you sure the public keys are the same at both ends?

Comment: I'm sure that they should be the same at both ends. I'm using the exact same method to read the key pair from a file in both cases.

Comment: I'm sure they should be the same at both ends too, otherwise the process won't work, but that's not what I asked. Have you checked?

Comment: By "should be the same," I meant "they are the same unless somehow magically reading a key from a file is nondeterministic," not "if they aren't the same, the program fails."

Comment: I repeat. Have you checked? Was the file transferred intact?

Comment: The object definitely was transferred intact. so.getObject() on the receiver returns the transferred object. I guess I could print out the bytes of the signature and inspect them, as well, but that's not going to be different, since that would have been a problem in the two threads, one process scenario.